# VisualBasic error in C# project

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting this error when trying to open a form. It cant find:

```
microsoft.visualbasic.PowerPacks.Vs. Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
```

The weird thing is, that it says Visual Basic, and I am using C#. All the other forms open fine, but not this one.

Comment: Well, presumably your form refers to a library which requires that assembly. Unfortunately we don't have any context to help you.

Comment: i get this error in one pc. The App Works fine in the server pc. All the App was made inn c#

Comment: It sounds like you're using a control that relies on the VB Power Pack (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25169). You may need to include the assembly with your application .

Comment: @Flezcano I don't know this hotel... But it still seems you are using a control that requires the `microsoft.visualbasic.PowerPacks.Vs` assembly.

Comment: OK, if so, I suspect that you need to deploy this assembly alongside your application.  to learn if it is required by your app, run your project from VS, open the problematic form, press the pause and invoke the Debug-->Windows-->Modules dialog.  If this assembly was loaded, add it to the redistributable list of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that an assembly happens to include "visual basic" in it's name doesn't mean it's specific to VB.  All VB code, as well as C# code, (and some other languages as well) all compile down to the same intermediate language (IL) code.  This idea is to encompass the ".NET languages" which, while they have a different syntax and higher level goals and intentions, have a common lower level implementation.  You can use any (well, technically not any, but almost any) .NET dll from either C# or VB.

In this particular case your code is referring (possibly indirectly) to a particular .NET assembly called "microsoft.visualbasic.PowerPacks"; consequently you need to have access to that assembly for your program to run.